# query about address of object while we are assigning an object to another

Tags: c++, c++11

i know that when i assign an object to another then they have both same address.but i wanted to visualize that but it is not showing as per my concept.i have had two object t1 and t2 are those object and i am assigning t1 in t2 and according to the concept t1 and t2's address should be same but it is printing different/

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
class Test
{ public:
int a=1,b=2,c=2;
};


int main()
{
Test t1;
Test t2=t1;
cout<<(&t2)<<endl<<(&t1)<<endl;
cout<<t2.a<<" "<<t1.a<<endl;
t1.a=10;
  cout<<t2.a<<" "<<t1.a<<endl;

}
```

Comment: "We know that" followed by complete nonsense...

Comment: Who is this "we" you're referring to? It seems to be a group with some strange beliefs.

Comment: you seem a little confused about pointers and objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you "know" is wrong. An object is a region of storage in memory. So two different objects, by definition, must have different addresses. `t1` and `t2` are different objects. With this initialization:

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

`t2` is a new object. Its initial value (the members a, b and c, in this case) is copied from `t1`, but they are completely separate objects, with different addresses. Changes to one will not affect the other.

```
t2.a = 77;     // no effect on t1.a
```